# Why does not the contents change in the button?

Tags: android

my project when click the two button, displays the number of times the button is pressed today.

when click A button, show how many times the a button was pressed on C button.
and click B button show how many times the a button was pressed on D button.

my source

```
aBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ClickCount();
    }
});

bBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ClickCount();
    }
});

public void ClickCount() {
    Button cBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cBtn);
     Button dBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dBtn);
    //a button click count work
    //1,,2,,,3,,,4,
    cBtn.setText(String.valueOf(resultC));
    dBtn.setText(String.valueOf(resultD));
}
```

first I try check `Log.d(TAG, resultC , resultD)` 
Log is normally it increase.

but `setText` only increase count resultC.

if change line dBtn and cBtn.

```
 dBtn.setText(String.valueOf(resultD));
 cBtn.setText(String.valueOf(resultC));
```

only display count dBtn resultD.

the log is incremented in both resultC and resultD.
but display result. only resultC with setText first appears

how to fix this problem?i know this problem very basically.
but I don't know this problem.

thanks.

Comment: Move this to onCreate`Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cBtn);
     dBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dBtn)`  and declare btn and dBtn as class members. Also where do you increment resultD and resultC?

Comment: you didn't show how you increment and log your values.

Comment: @Raghunandan     resultC and resultD increase on `ClickCount() `    cBtn, dBtn already member variable.

Comment: @hyunwookcho then there is no need to initialize buttons every time on Click.

Comment: Can you add some more of your code? Like the entire file? There's nothing wrong here, except you're getting the buttons on every click the user performs.

Comment: did you got your answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its happening because you are not increasing value of resultC and
>   resultD
>
> so try this :

```
aBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       resultC=resultC+1;
       ClickCount();
    }
});

bBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       resultD=resultD+1;
       ClickCount();
    }
});

public void ClickCount() {
    Button cBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cBtn);
     Button dBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dBtn);
    //a button click count work
    //1,,2,,,3,,,4,
    cBtn.setText(String.valueOf(resultC));
    dBtn.setText(String.valueOf(resultD));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Button at class level instead local function level

```
 Button cBtn;
 Button dBtn;
```

Initialise Buttons into the onCreate() callback instead of ClickCount() function:

```
cBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cBtn);
dBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dBtn);
```

What about if you return the count from function and set it into your onClickListener like below:

```
aBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       int count=ClickCount();
       cBtn.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
});

bBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       int count=ClickCount();
       dBtn.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
});
```

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I don't think this would solve the problem, but it's common sense and a best practice. He's accessing and retrieving the buttons everytime another one is clicked.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Yup

Comment: then please don't answer with anything that is not solving a problem. Answers should contain only solutions. For everything else use comments

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
    aBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ClickCount("a");
    }
});

bBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ClickCount("b");
    }
});

public void ClickCount(String key) {
    Button cBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cBtn);
     Button dBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dBtn);
    //a button click count work
    //1,,2,,,3,,,4,
    if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
       cBtn.setText(String.valueOf(resultC));
    }
    if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
    dBtn.setText(String.valueOf(resultD));
    }
}
```